# DB Validation on insert or update allow only one category based on order ID

Tags: postgresql, odoo-9

I would like to add Database side validation to allow only one category based on Order ID using SQL_Constraints or Check constraint.

Table: order_line_table
Example allow to insert or update same category only based on order id

```
Id     Order_id  Categ_id
1        1         4
2        1         4
3        1         4
4        2         5
5        2         5
```

Example not allow to insert or update different category based on order id

```
Id    Order_id Categ_id
6          3         4
7          3         5
```

I tried below code its working in server side. But using web service xmlrpc validation is not working.

```
@api.one
@api.constrains('order_line')
def _check_category(self):
    list_categ = []
    filter_categ = []        
    if self.order_line:
        order_line_vals = self.order_line
        for line_vals in order_line_vals:
            for line in line_vals:
                categ_id = line.categ_id and line.categ_id.id or False
                list_categ.append(line.categ_id.id)
                if isinstance(line, dict):
                    list_categ.append(line['categ_id'])
        filter_categ = list(set(list_categ))            
        if len(filter_categ) > 1:
            raise UserError(_('Only one product category is allowed!'))
```

Answer (score 1):

At first I misunderstood your question, so I'm updating the answer.

To achieve your goal you could use [`EXCLUDE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE) [constraint](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/137033/constraint-on-row-value-based-on-values-in-other-rows/137037) in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE order_line_table 
(
    Id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
    Order_id INT, 
    Categ_id INT, 
    EXCLUDE USING GIST 
    (
        Order_id WITH =, 
        Categ_id WITH <>
    )
);
```

To support `GIST` index over `<>` operator you [have to install an additional](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37351/postgresql-exclude-using-error-data-type-integer-has-no-default-operator-class) PostgreSQL extension `btree_gist`:

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;
```

Demo:

```
# INSERT INTO order_line_table (Order_id, Categ_id) VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT 0 1

# INSERT INTO order_line_table (Order_id, Categ_id) VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT 0 1

# INSERT INTO order_line_table (Order_id, Categ_id) VALUES (1, 3);
ERROR:  conflicting key value violates exclusion constraint "orders_order_id_category_id_excl"
DETAIL:  Key (Order_id, Categ_id)=(1, 3) conflicts with existing key (Order_id, Categ_id)=(1, 2).
```

Comment: It works in reverse. Actual my requirement allow only same category based on order_id.